# i am having too many menuitems in menubar. i want to scroll via mouse

Tags: vb.net-2010

I have some menus that contain many menuitems. Mouse wheel doesn't scroll them. I have to use the keyboard arrows or click the arrows at top and bottom. Is it possible to use the mouse wheel to scroll toolstrip menu items? in vb.net  Thanks

Comment: can someone help plzz

Answer (score 0):

I have done this by list box because i dint got anything.
i have even use text box so that i can sort my data easily as it has too many menu items 
It scrolls easily n get sorted by text box so i can easily find my menu items 
thanks.